# Error when creating Python GUI using Tkinter: “no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable”

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

last few days I've been working to create a GUI using Tkinter

This morning my code still worked, but now it crashed with said error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TKtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    master = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

My code is as simple as it gets:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
```

Note: I am *not* using SSH. This is just my Pi 4 connected via HDMI to the 7 inch touchscreen.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Try setting $DISPLAY to ":0.0" -- type `DISPLAY=:0.0` at the terminal.

Comment: Done that..  but still same error

Comment: I finally solved this. Detailed my answer here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118928/60683